# How do I set my transaction's gas to 0.5 ether?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I am trying to set my gas to 0.5 ether, but I'm not sure how to do that. I have a transaction tx here:

```
var tx = {
        to: "0x73E7D230586B118898aA1FB95FAA6E4119FA0996",
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('10', 'gwei'),
        gasLimit: ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.5', 'ether')
    }
```

It gives me this error
`Error: tx fee (5000000000.00 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether)`

What do I set for my gas price and gas limit?

Thanks!

Comment: First: value is not the gas, it is extra ether to send with the tx, it will not pay the gas fee. Second the gas limit and gas price depends on the network.

Comment: The max gas limit is how much gas u are willing to pay for. A block on ethereum and Test nets is about 12000000 big. u need here to give the gas limit as biginteger , I don’t think that ur tx need a whole block, u need to test that locally and then u get about how much gas does ur tx usually need , try maybe first with 2000000 Gaslimit

Comment: Gas price is the amount u want to pay for each 1 used gas. It depends on which network are sending the tx to. The main ethereum net is a little bit expensive. On the nest it is enough to give 5 Gwei as price

Comment: so you are wiling to pay around 1 thousand dollars for a transaction? You must be a rich guy!  Maybe you want to send some free ETH to us, poor people who deploys their contracts on Sunday morning to save on gas costs?

Answer (score 0):

```
Gas cost of a transaction = gas consumed * gas price
```

In a normal eth transfer, gas consumed is 21000. So now you have to set the gas price such that the multiplication is 0.5 ETH.

```
var tx = {
  to: "0x73E7D230586B118898aA1FB95FAA6E4119FA0996",
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
  gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.5').div(21000), // 0.5 ETH divided by 21000
}
```

It is not necessary that you set `gasLimit` value, ethers.js estimates it for you. (Ethers.js will put `gasLimit: 21000` for you automatically).

Note: since 0.5 ETH is not perfectly divisible by 21000, total gas consumed will be 0.49999 ETH something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`gasLimit` is the number of *units* of gas used by the transaction, not the actual value of that gas. what your code is trying to do is to create a transaction with a gas cost of 10 gwei (0,00000001 ether)/gas unit, using 0.5*10^18 gas units. Effectively resulting in the transaction costing you 0.00000001 x 0.5 x 10^18 = 5 billion ETH (maybe thats a bit overpriced). However, since your  transaction is a simple transfer, it wont actually consume more than 21000 units of gas. If you REALLY wish to pay 0.5 eth in gas fees (i couldnt  see a reason for that, but whatever floats your boat i guess), you'd need to set the gas *price* (not limit) so your gas price x 21000 = 0.5 eth. O.5 ETH is 5000000000 gwei, so your gas price would need to be 5000000000/21000 = 238095 gwei.